# JQuery: альтернатива функции wrap

Tags: jquery, функции

Вообщем есть функция `.wrap`, она как мне известно оборачивает нужный вам элемент в теги.
Вот таким способом.

```
$('#array').wrap('<span class="arrow"></span>');
```

Как это выглядит на стр.

```
<span class="arrow">
<div id="array"></div>
</span>
```

Подскажите как сделать что бы выглядело вот так.

```
<span class="arrow">
<span class="under"></span>
<div id="array"></div>
</span>
```

Т.е чтобы обернуло элемент в теги и сверху ещё поставить одни теги.
UPDATE. Или даже просто достаточно чтоб тег <span class="arrow"> не оборачивал элемент <div id="array"> а добовлялся внутрь элемента. Да думаю так даже лутше будет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#array').wrap('<span class="arrow"></span>');
$('<span class="under"></span>').insertBefore('#array');
```

[.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно